# Java: return pointer argument from *.dll void method

Tags: java, c, pointers, dll, void

I´m using the methods of a dynamic link library "xpcapi.dll" using jna.

One of the original methods of the *.dll in C is:

`void xPCGetParamName(int port, int paramIdx, char *blockName, char 
*paramName);`

I can declare the pointers `char *blockName` and `char *paramName` in java as:

`void xPCGetParamName(int port, int paramIdx, String blockName,  String paramName);`

but how can I return the pointers `char *blockName` and `char *paramName` in java?

Here is the explanation of the method `xPCGetParamName`:

[xPCGetParamName](https://de.mathworks.com/help/xpc/api/xpcgetparamname.html)

It say: "the parameter name is returned and stored in *paramName*"

Here is my Code until now:

```
package slrt;

import com.sun.jna.Library;


public interface XpcapiMethods extends Library {

int xPCOpenTcpIpPort(String ipAddress, String ipPort);
void xPCGetParamName(int port, int paramIdx, String blockName,  String paramName);

}
```

and

```
package slrt;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import slrt.XpcapiMethods;

public class xCommunication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        XpcapiMethods xpcMethods =
                (XpcapiMethods)Native.loadLibrary("xpcapi", XpcapiMethods.class);

        int tcpIpPort = xpcMethods.xPCOpenTcpIpPort("192.168.20.1", "22222");
        xpcMethods.xPCGetParamName(tcpIpPort, 1, "", "");

        System.out.println(tcpIpPort);

    }

}
```

Maybe someone had a similar problem or knows a way around it? 
Thanks a lot!